# Existence of a non semi-simple module over an alternating algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $A$ be the $2^{n}$-dimensional unital alternating algebra generated by $x_i$, where $i=1,...,n$.

I am looking for a non-semisimple $A$-module, i.e. a vector-space with $A$-action which is not a direct sum of simple $A$-modules.

Does such an module exists?

Comment: I haven't worked with alternating algebras before. Do they have identity?

Comment: Yes, they do. I will add this.

Comment: I'm not sure what construction you have in mind. I think I've seen something like this before where some relations are defined between the $x_i$'s and $y_i$'s. Usually though I hear the name used as a synonym for the exterior algebra, like  [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exterior+algebra).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ring with identity has a non-semisimple module iff it is not a semisimple as a module over itself... so you already have an example in hand, apparently.

Comment: In don’t see which example you mean. Why would the alternating algebra be semi-simple as a module over itself?

Comment: @user114179 What I mean is that all right $R$-modules are semisimple iff $R_R$ is semisimple. This is a basic result in noncommutative algebra. I don't really know what alternating algebras look like, but if they're anything like exterior algebras, then I think they probably have a nonzero Jacobson radical, and so they aren't semisimple.

Comment: Oh sorry, this result I know and you are right alternating algebra is the same as exterior algebra. But I do not know anything about Jacobson radicals :(

Comment: @user114179 Jacobson radicals are again an elementary aspect of semisimple rings. It would be worth your time to investigate the theory. In the meantime you have your answer: the ring itself cannot be a semisimple module.

Comment: Can you say why the radical is non zero? Is this indeed true?

Comment: We also need the algebra to be artinian don’t we?

Comment: @user114179 Being finite dimensional, it is obviously Artinian.  If I remember correctly, the exterior algebra even has a unique maximal right ideal.